# Pass listview child event to parent

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on a Android application, using Android studio.

I have a listview of layouts, with buttons inside these layouts, one of them is "Close".
I want my listview to remove the layout number n when i click on the "Close" button ,of the layout number n.

Something like the "Output" tag in angular2, to pass the click event of my layout to its parent.

My listview adapter :

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {


    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<MyModel> models) {
        super(context, 0, models);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_my_component, parent, false);
        }

        convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //How to pass this event to my activity ?
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In my activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //blablabla before

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    list_models = new ArrayList<MyModel>();

    //Add some models

    adapter = new CreditCardListViewAdapter(MyActivity.this, list_models);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //blablabla after
}
```

So I want that when the onClick() is called, i remove the element from list_models and update the adapter.

Comment: Show you listview adapter

Comment: I added the code. I think it is very regular, not a lot of fantasy here.

Comment: When you say remove my layout, do you mean delete that row of the list view of delete the whole list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this inside of the onClick

```
models.remove(position); 
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solve this precise problem but what about the general problem of sending an event from child to parent ? Perhaps it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Is that there is no way to pass an event with a custon adapter, still you can pass your listview as a parameter to the adapter and manage it there

Comment: Thank you. What a lack for a so big platform as the Android API ...I'll have to work at Google to change that.

Comment: Haha lets hope, I forgot, you could create an interface for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use BaseAdapter that is more advance and easy to use in BaseAdapter you can do anything in a listitem like setting text view, image view and anything else.